# Make a line in visio change colour when another object changes colour

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I want to change the line color of a line when the foreground color of another object is changed. Is it possible to link the line color directly with a formula in shapesheet?
I was thinking something like "LineColor"=GetRef(linked-objectname.GetRef(FillForegnd))
I've usedd shapesheet to change the foreground color of the "master/controlling" objects already so if its possible it would be good to continue to use that

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You mean when changed to any color, or fixed state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LineColor = Sheet.[some ID]!FillForegnd

This formula make current shape line color same as fill foreground color of another shape with ID = [some ID].
Where [some ID] is number! Final formula looks like *Sheet.100500!FillForegnd*

Comment: This worked out perfectly when linking to another line. Thank you very much!

How do I link it to a different object? I see that I have a line that is called "Sheet.1219", but I want to link it to a valve, and that is called "Screw-down valve.1254" but replacing "Sheet.1219" with that just gives me an error. Where do I find the name of the object to link to?

Comment: Sorry, for delay with answer! At last summer i create this tool which can help to get reference to another shape: [ShapeSheet snippet](https://surrogate-tm.github.io/snippets/shapesheet_en.html)

Comment: Wow, this is awsome! Thanks so much for sharing!
It's a pain that MS haven't made this easier in the first place though...